# Force EC2 Instance Replacement When Updating UserData in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm using the `UserData` field in a `CloudFormation` template to install software on the instance. When I update the `UserData` I would like `CloudFormation` to replace the instance. However, `UserData` is not a replace field and as a result the instance is stopped but not replaced and the new `UserData` script is never run.

Is there a way I can update the `UserData` with `CloudFormation`?

I'm referring to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html).

Comment: Have you ever solved this?

Comment: For anyone generating CloudFormation templates via the AWS CDK, you can specify this in the EC2 Instance construct: `userDataCausesReplacement` in TypeScript, `user_data_causes_replacement` in Python…

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the documentation, updating user data doesn't necessarily (and in most cases shouldn't) require replacing the instance.

You could try and run the updated User Data script from a Systems Manager command. The script should be stored in /var/lib/cloud/instances/[instance-id]/user-data.txt

OR you can set it to run after rebooting. Check out the guide at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/ , and more examples at https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html